# NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching Support

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl, graphics

Apple has a [technical note](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1734/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010791) mentioning that it's possible to prevent your Macbook from switching to the Discrete card for OpenGL. However, it hasn't been updated since last April. It mentions in the note that the `NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching` flag only works on 2011 Macbook Pros, but that seems like out of date documentation at this time.

My question is: is there a more updated method to enable this functionality? Since that time, both Lion and Mountain Lion have been released along with a whole new line of Macbooks, and I'd think that there must be some sort of path to prevent GPU switching, especially with Intel's integrated graphics getting better and better.

For the record I've tried the `NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching` flag on a Mid-2012 Retina Macbook Pro to no avail.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870304/dont-automatically-switch-to-the-higher-end-discrete-gpu) question is related, but the solution there is to look at GfxCardStatus to see how it does it. I don't want to control the GPU for all apps, just mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I was having was that I wasn't supporting multiple renderers as per [this technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2229/_index.html). I needed to add to my `NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute` list the `NSOpenGLPFAAllowOfflineRenderers` attribute. Now that I have that, my app won't automatically trigger the discrete card, and I can actually switch between integrated and discrete at will.

Answer (score 0):

It should still work as far as I know. At least it did for Rdio, see this link for more info: 
http://zacwe.st/blog/rdio-discrete-card

I'm also using the Retina MBP... and I have also applied this successfully to another app, so it's not just Rdio-specific.

Maybe the specific app you're trying to modify is sandboxed, or doesn't have the correct plist?

Comment: i can confirm NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching still works on 2012 MBP retina. NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching has to be set to YES, the logic seems reversed...